# Connections <hints> section in UI file

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I am analyzing xml containing UI generated by Qt Designer. I came across entries whose meaning I do not understand. They concern signal/slot connections:

```
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>248</x>
     <y>254</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
```

What information does the `<hints>` section contain? I haven't found anything about it in the documentation while it's hard to guess what the hints and labels mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<hint>` have information about the position of the arrow that are used to connect the signals and slots in QtDesigner